# How to delete a item from list without updating it

Tags: 2007

How can i delete a list item from a shrepoitn list without updting the list. my problem is that there are 10,000 users who interact with same list (cannot change scenario) and if one user deletes the item using event receiver (he does something) then another user do something and another event receiver tries to upload document to list when list is getting updated after deleting document.

problem = save conflict as list is being updated you cannot upload document.

Comment: Well you can use `this.EventFiringEnabled = false;` property at the beginning of the Event Receiver ?

Comment: I am confused.  How many items are in the scenario you are laying out? How long does it take your event receiver to complete? Do you need to update the list on every event receipt or do you simply intend to update the item?